# ADB command to open Chrome settings

Tags: android, adb

Is there an `adb` command to open settings within Chrome browser? Sorry if this has been asked before, but I searched everywhere and could not find anything regarding this.

Comment: Chrome is just a regullar app, and has no integration with ADB.

Comment: There could be some indirect way to open settings, but what exactly you will achieve with that. After opening the settings through adb, to do some actual settings you will have to use chrome , so there is no advantage even if you open settings through ADB